# sign in prompt causes "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive" ERROR

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-signin, google-identity

I'm using Google Sign In (Identity Services) to implement login/logout functionalities on my React web app. Everything except for the One Tap Prompt works just fine. The prompt itself even sometimes works (by working, I mean it triggers the callback function or is dismissed by the user without any issue), but so randomly that I haven't been able to find a pattern.

What happens is whenever the user tries to interact with the Google sign in button or the One Touch prompt, they do not respond, and the user is unable to dismiss/close the prompt, each click triggering the following error:

`[Intervention] Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5093566007214080`

The stack trace indicates the error occurs in the external GSI library, so I can't really do anything about it. Nothing in my own code creates an event listener.

Here's my code, for reference:

```
const GoogleSignIn = () => {
  const [gsiScriptLoaded, setGsiScriptLoaded] = useState(false);
  const GOOGLE_ID = "my Google Client Id";
  const googleSignInButton = useRef(null);

  const handleGoogleSignIn = (res: CredentialResponse) => {
    if (!res.clientId || !res.credential) return;

    const gToken = res.credential;
    (async () => {
      // some code to create a session on my server API and redirect the user to the main page
    })();
  };

  const initializeGsi = () => {
    if (!window.google || gsiScriptLoaded) return;

    setGsiScriptLoaded(true);
    window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: GOOGLE_ID,
      callback: handleGoogleSignIn,
      auto_select: false,
    });

    window.google?.accounts.id.renderButton(googleSignInButton.current, { type: "icon" });

    window.google?.accounts.id.prompt();
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");
    script.src = "https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client";
    script.onload = initializeGsi;
    script.async = false;
    script.id = "google-client-script";
    document.querySelector("body")?.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      window.google?.accounts.id.cancel();
      document.getElementById("google-client-script")?.remove();
    };
  });

  return (
    <div>
        <div ref={googleSignInButton} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default GoogleSignIn;
```

Removing the line
`window.google?.accounts.id.prompt();`
solves the problem entirely, but I should be able to use it on my login page without this type of error, right?

Comment: Did you read https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5093566007214080 ? And if you did, what part of your own code is getting flagged? (because nothing in the code you're showing creates an event listener)

Comment: Yes, I did. It just says that you should explicitly define the value of passive on two specific event listeners, otherwise they will default to passive: true.
But, as you said, nothing in my own code creates an event listener. Nothing is flagged either, the error occurs on runtime. That's where I'm stuck.

Comment: where does `window.google` come from? because this might just be a bug in whatever library introduces that.